# Wordcloud + corpus error in R

Tags: r, twitter, corpus

I want to use the Wordcloud function for doing a cloud on twitter data. I have installed the twitter package and the working with the api. I do the following after that.

```
bigdata <- searchTwitter("#bigdata", n=20)

bigdata_list <- sapply(bigdata, function(x) x$getText())
bigdata_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(bigdata_list))
bigdata_corpus <- tm_map(bigdata_corpus, content_transformer(tolower), lazy=TRUE)
bigdata_corpus <- tm_map(bigdata_corpus, removePunctuation, lazy=TRUE)
bigdata_corpus <- tm_map(bigdata_corpus, 
                           function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords()), lazy=TRUE)
wordcloud(bigdata_corpus)
```

This produces the error message for the Wordcloud command:

```
Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "try-error"
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mclapply(x$content[i], function(d) tm_reduce(d, x$lazy$maps)) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
2: In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
```

I have tried different corpus commands but cant seem to get it right. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
library("tm")
# Transform your corpus in a term document matrix
bigdata_tdm <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(bigdata_corpus))
# Get the frequency by words
bigdata_freq <- data.frame(Words = rownames(bigdata_tdm), Freq = rowSums(bigdata_tdm), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# sort
bigdata_freq <- bigdata_freq[order(bigdata_freq$Freq, decreasing = TRUE), ]
# keep the 50 most frequent words
bigdata_freq <- bigdata_freq[1:50, ]

# Draw the wordcloud
library("wordcloud")
wordcloud(words = bigdata_freq$Words, freq = bigdata_freq$Freq)
```

With `tm_0.6` and `wordcloud_2.5` both ways works.